# NuGet install-package failing

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm attempting to install xunit version 2.1.0.. However I'm getting the following exception:

Install-Package : Exception 'System.AggregateException' thrown when trying to add source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Please verify all your o
nline package sources are available.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  xunit -Version 2.1.0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Any ideas on whats going wrong? Sadly google is not giving me anything helpful..

Comment: Have you taken a look at your nuget configuration? If you have any sources that have not been configured correctly this is the exception that will be thrown.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is an old question, but it just happened to me, and the solution may help others: In my case it was due to a package source that was not available anymore and I needed to remove it from the NuGet Package manager configuration:

**Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> go to Package Sources and remove the source that is generating the problem.**

And be aware of the fact that this server is not responding! If it is one server of your own, it would be good for you to check what is happening with it. ;)

Comment: Your answer lead me to discover that I was not able to install EntityFramework because was connected to our company's local Nuget repository. After connecting, thru a VPN, to our company, installation EF installed successfully. Nice!

Comment: removing all package sources and adding the official nuget.org will make it work

Comment: Unreal.  I removed a source that wasn't even selected and this started to work.